# Как правильно переписать фрагмент кода с JQuery в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как переписать такой фрагмент кода на чистый JS?

```
$('.temp').each(function(i){
  var tempMin = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[i].day.mintemp_c);
  var tempMax = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[i].day.maxtemp_c);
  $(this).append("<p>" + tempMin + "/" + tempMax  + "&degC");
});
```

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("temp")).forEach(function(e, i) {
  var tempMin = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[i].day.mintemp_c);
  var tempMax = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[i].day.maxtemp_c);
  e.innerHTML = "<p>" + tempMin + "/" + tempMax + "&degC</p>";
});
```

Comment: все-таки `e.innerHTML = ...` имеет побочный эффект удаления всего существующего содержимого

Answer (score 1):

```
var temps = document.querySelectorAll('.temp');
for (var i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
  var tempMin = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[i].day.mintemp_c);
  var tempMax = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[i].day.maxtemp_c);
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = tempMin + "/" + tempMax  + "&degC";
  temps[i].appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.temp');

for (var q=0; q<els.length; ++q) {
  var tempMin = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[q].day.mintemp_c);
  var tempMax = Math.floor(weather.forecast.forecastday[q].day.maxtemp_c);
  els[q].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<p>" + tempMin + "/" + tempMax  + "&degC");
}
```